# Access learning rate with exponential_decay

Tags: tensorflow

I defined a global step like this:

```
global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(FLAGS.starter_lr,
    global_step,
    1000,
    0.96,
    staircase=True)
```

And I am trying to print out the learning rate to stdout every n iterations. I tried adding the learning_rate to the list of ops I get but the learning rate I get does not decay.

```
variables = [loss, training_summary, learning_rate, train_step]
current_loss, t_summary, lr, _ = sess.run(variables, feed_dict)
```

Am I misunderstanding what the `learning_rate` object is?

[EDIT]
My training step is defined like this:

```
train_step = (
        tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
        .minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
        )
```

Comment: Are you incrementing the global step? Can you show where `train_step` is coming from?

Comment: Sorry that was quite unclear, I just added it

Comment: I did the same things in a toy example and I could see the learning_rate going down. Maybe try using a smaller `decay_steps` (say 10 instead of current 1000) and `staircase=False` to make sure the problem is not simply "I did not wait long enough for it to decay"